# kswapd0 problem

Tags: release-loki, kernel, swap

I've been using elementary OS for about a month, and the problem of `kswapd0` using 100% of the CPU appeared both on my PC and Netbook. Is there any way to fix it? I've installed the 4.15 kernel and thought that the new kernel would help, but still nothing. I even disabled swap cause I use an SSD, but it still eats my CPU after some time.

Does anyone else have this problem or I am the chosen one?